# Looping through a recordset to retrieve values

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
returnAddress = "SELECT Address_ID FROM Address_Bridge WHERE Customer_ID = 
76541 AND Company_ID = 23540"

set db = currentDB
set rst = db.openRecordSet(returnAddress)
```

This is my recordset. It returns all address IDs for a specific combination of Customer and Company. I anticipate there being anywhere from 1 to 7 Address IDs being returned by this recordset. I need to use each of them as values in an Append query. I'm just not sure how to access them.

```
For Each Address_ID in rst
    perform update query
next
```

That's my assumption of how to do it, but I've tried several variations and all have returned errors. If anyone could assist me with the specific syntax for this, it would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it.

```
Dim sValue As String
Do until rst.EOF
  sValue=rst!FieldName

  ' do other stuff

  rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: For completeness, you might want to update your example to show how to retrieve a field value.

Comment: I was stuck staring at my code so long I guess it turned to latin. I was using `rst.next` instead of `rst.MoveNext`. I will try this. Thank you!